# Gantry5 index.php jdoc:include

Tags: joomla

I'm trying to add this code:

```
$option = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getCmd('option');
$view   = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getCmd('view');
if ($option == 'com_content' && $view == 'category') {
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="showcase" />
}
```

to my index.php (/rt_notio/index.php) of a Gantry 5 (Rockettheme Notio) template on a Joomla 3.10.12 / PHP 7.4.33 CMS.

But every time when I call the page I got a 404 error. Seems that the system doesn't render this code (especially the jdoc:include command)
To implement such a code in Garnty5 there is obviously another way to do this, but how and where?
What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks for answering!

My expectations is: Rendering the index.php to get my page online and inject the module "showcase" only on category pages, not on every article page.  And no, Advanced module Manager would not help. This great piece of software gives me a lot of weird errors in conjunction with Gantry5/Rockettheme template/Joomla. https://docs3.regularlabs.com/advancedtemplatemanager/going-further/not-compatible-with

Answer (score 0):

If you were trying to add a custom module position, you need to add it as a particle in Gantry. They have a detail instruction [here](https://docs.gantry.org/gantry5/particles/position), no coding required.